# Poltergeist current_url command is returning page_info hash instead of a URL

Tags: poltergeist

### Problem

I have an rspec feature test that is using `capybara/poltergeist` with `:js => true` and is doing something really simple:

```
visit borrow_path 
click_on "Get Started" 
page.should have_content "Create Your Account"
```

Clicking `Get Started` takes the user to our sign up page and then poltergeist raises a Timeout Error on the `page.should have_content` assertion, despite the screenshot of the page confirming that the content is, in fact, on the page.

The error is:

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_content "Create Your Account"
Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError:
  Timed out waiting for response to {"name":"find","args":["xpath","/html"]}. It's possible that this happened because something took a very long time (for example a page load was slow). If so, setting the Poltergeist :timeout option to a higher value will help (see the docs for details). If increasing the timeout does not help, this is probably a bug in Poltergeist - please report it to the issue tracker.
     # ./spec/features/borrower/signup_spec
```

We've tried upping the timeout to 5 minutes, still the same error.

This doesn't happen consistently, every few runs the test will pass.

### Details

With that in mind, I turned :debug on in our setup as follows:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  # use 'page.driver.debug' as a js debugger
  # see https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/tree/v1.5.0#remote-debugging-experimental
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :timeout => 300, :inspector => true, :debug => false, :window_size => [1280, 1400], :js_errors => true)
end
```

and re-ran the tests. The failed spec's output looks as follows:

```
{"name"=>"current_url", "args"=>[]}
{"response"=>{"page_id"=>126, "ids"=>[0]}}

  An error occurred in an after hook
    URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): {"page_id"=>126, "ids"=>[0]}
    occurred at /home/rof/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:176:in `split'

{"name"=>"current_url", "args"=>[]} 
{"response"=>"http://127.0.0.1:49891/users/sign_up?m=borrower"} 
{"name"=>"current_url", "args"=>[]} 
{"response"=>"http://127.0.0.1:49891/users/sign_up?m=borrower"} 
{"name"=>"body", "args"=>[]} 
{"response"=>"http://127.0.0.1:49891/users/sign_up?m=borrower"}
```

I can't find any hints as to why a call to `current_url` is returning the page_id hash instead of a URL, but this actually breaks all subsequent feature tests and causes `find` to always return `true`:

```
{"name"=>"find", "args"=>["xpath","/html"]} 
{"response"=>"true"}
```

Which causes this exception on all subsequent tests (whether they're tagged :js => true or not):

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `[]' for true:TrueClass
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/poltergeist-1.5.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:54:in `find'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/poltergeist-1.5.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:114:in `find'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/poltergeist-1.5.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:118:in `find_xpath'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:154:in `block in resolve_query'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:77:in `synchronize'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:150:in `resolve_query'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:129:in `all'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:107:in `block in assert_no_selector'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:81:in `synchronize'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:106:in `assert_no_selector'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:396:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:81:in `reset!'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara.rb:253:in `block in reset_sessions!'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara.rb:253:in `each'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara.rb:253:in `reset_sessions!'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.2.1/lib/capybara/rspec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:471:in `instance_eval'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:471:in `instance_eval_with_rescue'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:242:in `instance_eval_with_rescue'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:31:in `run'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:85:in `block in run'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:85:in `each'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:85:in `run'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in `run_hook'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:350:in `run_after_each_hooks'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:298:in `run_after_each'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:120:in `block in run'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.14.0/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:158:in `call'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.14.0/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:158:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ControllerExampleGroup>'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `instance_eval_with_args'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in run'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:104:in `call'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:104:in `run'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in `run_hook'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:340:in `run_around_each_hooks'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:256:in `with_around_each_hooks'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:58:in `report'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
# /home/rof/cache/bundler/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Hi user3466337, I'm experiencing similar problems. All tests pass in development but we have tests randomly failing with same error on CI server (Semaphore). Did you found any solution?

Comment: Logged as a Poltergeist issue at https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/482